# Outlook Focused Inbox is unavailable?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016, which I was anxious to upgrade to in order to use the new Focused Inbox feature. However, Focused Inbox was not available in the View ribbon menu as I expected. After digging around, I found and added the "Show Focused Inbox" command to a custom "Other" group on the ribbon -- only to find it is grayed out:

[image]

I can't find any documentation out there that would explain this. I use Focused Inbox in the Outlook iPhone app, so I doubt its a feature our Exchange admin would have bothered to disable. Any idea why this would be, or how I can activate the feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Outlook 2016 help page:

> Focused Inbox was first released on Outlook for iOS and Android. All
>   versions of Outlook that receive updates will soon become Focused
>   Inbox capable, including Outlook 2016 for Windows, Outlook 2016 for
>   Mac, Outlook on the web, and Mail for Windows 10. You'll see Focused
>   Inbox once your Office 365 or Outlook.com mailbox is enabled for it.

It sounds like they will enable it when they update Outlook 2016 to be compatible. If you read [here](https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/26/outlook-helps-you-focus-on-what-matters-to-you/), it sounds like it started rolling out to Office 365 customers in early September. I do not have it enabled on my version yet either.

Comment: You're right. The article you referenced was updated the next day: "**Editor’s note 10/7/2016:**  Update on rollout: Office 365 First Release users will become Focused Inbox enabled starting in late October. Worldwide rollout will take 4 – 6 weeks. Office 365 Standard Release users will be enabled in mid to late November and will take 6-8 weeks to be available worldwide. Once enabled, users will be able to see the Focused Inbox in Outlook for Mac, iOS, Android and the web immediately. Outlook 2016 for Windows and Outlook for Windows 10 Mobile will show the Focused Inbox in November."

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Outlook 2016 on Windows (May 2017) but I'm still not able to view the option for focused inbox in View ribbon. I have enabled the same for the organization and for the user. Alsom I can view on the Outlook 365 web application and on Outlook for Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/10/14/managing-focused-inbox-in-office-365-and-outlook/

Footnote 2 was relevant in my case:

> Outlook 2016 for Windows(1), (2),(3)  16.0.7967.2xxx+  |  Version 1703 of Current Channel
>
> 1. requires the Office 365 subscription versions of the clients. Focused Inbox will not be delivered to Outlook for Mac 2011, or the perpetual versions of Outlook 2013 for Windows and Outlook 2016 for Windows.
> 2. **Requires Modern Authentication to be enabled for Exchange Online.**
> 3. We are also working on an additional update, which will remove the requirement of Modern Authentication for Focused Inbox to work. That will come in a future fork.